# Batch crop images to fixed height (CLI)

Tags: imagemagick, graphicsmagick, mogrify

I have images of variable height and width, and I want to crop them all to be 200 pixels high, without any resizing. i.e. their width will remain the same, and height will be 200px. I want to use "north" gravity for this.

Any CLI tool that allows batch processing would be OK - imagemagick/mogrify, gm, etc. I've tried to figure this out but can't find any option to just leave width unspecified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mogrify *.png -gravity North -extent x200 -path ./complete
```

The [mogrify](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-tools.php#mogrify) utility would suite your batch task with [-gravity](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#gravity), [-extent](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#extent), and [-path](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#path) options:

Answer (score 1):

You could leave the width unspecified by, well, leaving the width unspecified, and use `extent` to do the cropping:

```
convert in.png -extent x200 out.png
```

or, say,

```
mogrify -extent x200 *.png
```

For the wizard example image, that would turn [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i412T.png) into [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QtRwR.png). You can see more resizing examples [on the examples site](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/), as well as [some different ways of doing cropping](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/).